# Get user email using Youtube API

Tags: node.js, api, youtube, youtube-api

How can I get authenticated user email using Youtube API?

I tried using [`channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list):

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

It doesn't return the email...

I communicate with Youtube API using [this NodeJS module](https://npmjs.org/package/youtube-api):

```
var Youtube = require("youtube-api");

Youtube.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    token: ACCESS_TOKEN
});

Youtube.channels.list({
    "part": "brandingSettings",
    "mine": true
}, function (err, data) {
    console.log(err, data);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a user's email address, you'll need to get their permission first during OAuth. Google's OAuth has a scope specifically for this. I'm not familiar with the Node.js `youtube-api` module, but you'll have to get it to include an additional OAuth scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. Then the email address will be available in the response from a request to http://googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo.

This post may be helpful: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/06/node-and-google-oauth/

Comment: I added the scope. What request must I make to get the email?

Comment: You don't need to make another request. The email will come back as part of the OAuth information for the user.

Comment: Hmm... The response of OAuth request contains only these keys: `{ "access_token" : "...", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600, "id_token" : "...", "refresh_token" : "..." }`. How can I get the email...?

Comment: Ah, no, you're right, my library was doing more than I realized. You'll want to hit https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo.

Comment: Good! Add this into your answer and then I will mark it. Thank you!