# How to get the email account that was used to create a specific YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How to get the email account that was used to create a specific YouTube channel?
Is there any PHP class or function that can help me? Or any kind of sample codes?
Thanks.

**Edit:** I have a YouTube channel and I uploaded some videos to this channel. Now, I need to delete on of this videos. But I for got login details (email address and password) to access this channel. I cannot remember which email address was used to create this channel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get user email using Youtube API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567135/get-user-email-using-youtube-api)

Answer (score 1):

After authenticating a user with OAuth, call and HTTP GET request on the [`channels/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint with the parameters `part=contentDetails` and `mine=true`.  If a `googlePlusUserId` is returned in the `contentDetails` dictionary, you can then call another request to the Google+ API's [`people`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/) endpoint to get the email address associated with that YouTube account.

Note that YouTube is now forcing all channels to be linked with a Google Account as of the v3 API.  There still may be some accounts that do not have a linked Google Account, but that is an minimal [edge case](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5261) according to Google.

If you have completely lost the email to your YouTube account and this is not an API question, you need to look at the YouTube support article for recovering your account and follow the steps [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/3219097?hl=en&rd=2).

Comment: This is not my problem. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @mukto90 updated my answer to point you to the account recovery page.