# YouTube Data API - Get Email address from channel ID

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to retrieve email address from channel Id? Or this is simply not possible? Is there any way to retrieve email address by any other means?

Comment: According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567135/get-user-email-using-youtube-api), you need to get their permission first during OAuth. Google's OAuth has a scope specifically for this. You may visit the link for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you. Just need to call it's api and get channel info.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

Comment: Channel info doesn't give you the email address. I need the email addresses of the respective channel assuming the fact that I got the Channel Id

Comment: @SarojHumagain did you find the email id from channel id.